# Remove <br> tags from the beginning and end of a string

Tags: php, regex

How would I, given a string like this (for example), remove all break (`<br>,<br />, and any other form`) tags from *only* the beginning and end of the string?

Original string:

```
<br>Hello, World! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NU7W7qe2R0A<br><br>
```

Output:

```
Hello, World! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NU7W7qe2R0A
```

If the original string has `<br>` tags in the middle of the string, i.e.:

```
<br>Hello, World!<br><br>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NU7W7qe2R0A<br><br>
```

It should output:

```
Hello, World!<br><br>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NU7W7qe2R0A
```

How would I achieve this results?

Comment: `/(^<br[^>]*>|<br[^>]*>$)/`

Comment: to answerers ; note op wants to handle several forms of <br>, <br/> <br />

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use `preg_replace` and a regular expression like this.

```
$s = '<br><br /><Br  ><br   />Hello, World!<br><br />testing 123<br  ><BR   /><br><br />';

$stripped = preg_replace('/^(<br\s*\/?>)*|(<br\s*\/?>)*$/i', '', $s);

var_dump($stripped);
```

Outputs:

```
string(57) "Hello, World!<br><br />testing 123"
```

Comment: @Riad I've added the `\\`, even though it doesn't seem to need them.

Comment: This could be a working solution, I can produce good results with this code, even for second OP's example with br tags in the middle of the string.

Comment: yeah..this code is working fine...its good practice to provide the `\\` characters to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 2):

To match `<br>` at the beginning and the end of a string use:

```
(?:\A<br\s*/?\s*>)+|(?:<br\s*/?\s*>)+$

$result = preg_replace('%(?:\A<br\s*/?\s*>)+|(?:<br\s*/?\s*>)+$%i', '', $text);
```

---

A more generalized regex is:

```
(?:\A<[a-z\d]+\s*/?\s*>)+|(?:<[a-z\d]+\s*/?\s*>)+$

$result = preg_replace('%(?:\A<[a-z\d]+\s*/?\s*>)+|(?:<[a-z\d]+\s*/?\s*>)+$%i', '', $text);
```

Answer (score -1):

I use this :

```
<?
$data = '<br>Hello, World!<br><br><br /><br>';
$filter = array('<br>','<br />'); 
$data = str_replace($filter,'',$data);
var_dump($data);
```

Comment: This will strip the br tags for sure, but OP wants to strip tags from beginning and the end of string, but not from the middle. Read his question carefully.

Answer (score -1):

This is what I use in my projects :

```
Code below will handle : <br>, <br >, <br   >, <br/>, <br />, <br   />

$data = "<br><br ><br/><br />test1<br><br  ><br />test2<br><br ><br/><br />";
$str = preg_replace('/^(<br\s*?\/?>)+|(<br\s*\/?>)+$/', '', $data);
echo $str;
```